# Restart Gif when scroll into view

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, gif, js-scrollintoview

I would like to "restart" a gif from the beginning when I scroll down or up, and come back into view.

So for exemple, my page load, the animation start -> I scroll down or up -> I come back to the div with the gif, the gif has been reset.

I have found this great piece of js in codepen, which is working great when I scroll to the top and come back, but doesn't work when I scroll Down and come back.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWvagO?editors=0010
the code looks like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var current = $(this).scrollTop(),
  path = '//cdn.pbrd.co/images/5QABxgAp7.gif',
  visible = $('img').css('opacity') != 0;

  if (current > 200) {
  if (!visible) $('img').attr('src', path).fadeTo(400,1);
  }
  else if (visible) $('img').fadeTo(0,0);
});
```

Is there a simple way to make it work and keeping the code simple like this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late and this might be a bad solution. However, I solved a similar problem by having two duplicated gifs and alternating between the two when 'restarting' the gif. This seamlessly restarted the gif when needed, and technically it was the same gif. Hope this helped, Good luck!